# Flex box contents overflow fix for Internet explorer?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10

This image part contains two images, light-green square image and the other image, with different pixels for height & width each other, and they are wrapped in a box with flex CSS, to align precisely to the lower image with having exact same responsive width.
display: flex was my last resort, after having failed attempt with display: table or float style which both could almost achieve responsive alignment but not a perfect fit on some occasion to the lower image by less than 1px width. So display: flex was nice before I noticed the browser compatibility issue. Firefox, chrome is fine, ms edge is also fine, but internet explorer 10(or 11?) has a problem, not minor but big one. I watched the issue on windows 8. The two images are separate on IE, they are enlarged and having new line between them. I didn't noticed that until watching the IE screen because user-agent emulator on chrome, safari and Firefox dev-tool show no issue.

I tried to avoid the known issue. I just applied display flex to the wrapping div and flex number to the children.

snippet : https://jsfiddle.net/83kcu03L/2/ ( a little modified version is https://jsfiddle.net/83kcu03L/5/)

```
    body{
  width:98%;
}
div{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#div1,#div2{
  width:50%;
  border:1px solid #333;
}
#div3{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
      border:1px solid #333;
      background-color:red;
}
#div4-1{
    -webkit-flex: 120%;
    -ms-flex: 120%;
    flex: 120%;
}
#div4-2{
    -webkit-flex: 398%;
    -ms-flex: 398%;
    flex: 398%;
}
#div5-1,#div5-2{
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 100% !important;
}
img{
     width: 100% !important;
}
#div13{
        border:1px solid #333;
      background-color:red;
}


    <body>
<div id="div1">1
<div id="div2">2

<div>

<div id="div3">3
<div id="div4-1"><a><img id="div5-1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/89x89/0f0"></a></div>
<div id="div4-2"><a><img id="div5-2"  src="http://via.placeholder.com/295x89/00f"></a></div>
</div>

<div id="div13"><div><a><div>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x144/a3f">
</div></a>
</div>
</div>

</div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Here, images in flex box would be enlarged and overflowed on IE10, (and IE11?).

IE emulator's result is here:
[enlarged and overflowed on IE10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkSX8.jpg)

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Your jsfiddle demo renders the same layout in Chrome, Firefox, Edge *and* IE11. So I don't see the problem.

Comment: @Michael_B Try IE10 on windows 8, it should have the problem. Also, IE emulator shows overflow issue for IE10 which you can see at the image link(but not showing any issue for IE11).